# How to pass sub-report total to main report to show grand total in RDLC?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I know so may people said it is not possible in SSRS, but those answers are two year old.

Is Microsoft allowing to this in newer version of SSRS?

The workaround solution for this question I saw is, maintaining the another dataset in main report with aggregate values to show the grand totals. This solution is not possible in my case as I was having hundreds of sub-reports in single report.

If this is still not supported in new version of reporting services what are the best alternatives for the huge datasets?

Comment: Hundreds of subreports is making SSRS do a lot of extra work. I would consider reworking the main dataset to contain the subreport data, and group by the main fields. Would need to see some sample data layout to give a more detailed reply

Comment: Hi @JerryRitcey , Thanks for your response. Hundreds of subreports is just an example I have given. I have similar problem with even 5 subreports. Let's assume each subreport is taking 2 seconds, so main report takes 10 (5*2) seconds to generate the report. If I try to get the aggregate values in main report, the report generation time goes to 20 seconds... It doesn't make sense...

Comment: A subreport is never going to be faster than having the data in the main dataset. If it is, something else is going on.

Comment: @JerryRitcey   Yes, main report is faster as it generally fetches Ids (for instance Employee Ids). A sub report is inside the table where each Id is passing to sub report to generate the amounts for Empoyee (which typically takes 2 seconds). Main report is nothing to do other fetching simple Ids. I wanted to  show sum of all these totals (grand total) on main report. I can't add another data set in main report to bring the grand total as main report it self takes time if I do so. Any suggestions?

Comment: We would need to see what you have tried so far with data examples to say more.